# Make two functions run parallely print output to different line

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make some kind of functions that run parallely with multiprocessing from python. The script looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def func1():
    for x in range(0,10000000):
          print(x, end = '\r')
def func2():
    for x in range(10000000,20000000):
          print(x, end ='\r')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func2)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

However, then I run this script both func1 and func2 override output of each other in the same line, but not in separate lines. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why the `\r`? Are you running on windows?

Comment: it can be big problem. Some consoles/terminals may have special codes to move cursor and you can add them to string to move text in expected place. But if console doesn't use codes then you can't solve it. You can check [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) or similar modules

Comment: @drum yes, I'm running it on windows

Comment: Try `\r\n` instead, or get rid of that completely

Comment: @khanhlpbao any feedback?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev sr I got sick few days ago. I'm trying your and Booboo method

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you print, the output is buffered, but if the *flush* keyword argument is `True`, the stream is forcibly flushed. This should help considerably. And there is no need to specify the *end* argument; the `print` function will use the correct codes to generate a newline by default:

```py
print(x, flush=True)
```

Comment: flush=True does not worked, the output still flood the screen